# Line up a border when one div has a scrollbar

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div id="box-1">
  <div class="sub-box"></div>
  <div class="sub-box"></div>
  <div class="sub-box"></div>
  <div class="sub-box"></div>
  <div class="sub-box"></div>
</div>
<div id="box-2">
  <div class="sub-box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box-1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: black;
}
#box-2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.sub-box {
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  border-right: 5px solid #FFF;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Calum/pen/IEbKj

The boarders of the two sub-boxes don't match up.
I don't want to give both sub-boxes scrollbars.
I don't want to change 20% to a pixel value.

How can I get the borders to line up? Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you asking why there's a scrollbar?

Comment: No, I wanted to know why the scrollbar changed the position of the border and how I could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The borders don't line up because the scrollbar is subtracting from the width of `#box-1`.  `20%` of `500px` - `<scrollbar>` makes box 1 a little less wide and thus places the border over a few pixels.

If you want scroll, you will not be able to use `%` for your width.

Comment: Thanks for being specific!

Answer (score 2):

scroll bars are generated by the browser and from my experience each browser draws them its own unique way... the only way to get this pixel perfect would be to remove the browser generated scroll bars and replace them with a custom one from a plugin... ( there are a few options if you do a google search )

one example: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

that way you can size and position your divs and the scroll bars specifically for optimal cross browser experience

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing overflow: auto; from #box-1

Comment: I need box-1 to scroll. Thanks for the suggestion.